# Perl - Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Net/SSH2.pm

Tags: perl, ssh, hash

I have created a perl that ssh to connect to multiple devices. I would like to check if ssh functions properly by connecting devices.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SSH2;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime;

open (OUTPUTS, ">ssh_Success$date.log" );
open (OUTPUTF, ">ssh_Fail$date.log" );

open( SWITCHIP, "ip.txt" ) or die "couldn't open ip.txt";

my $count = 0;

while (<SWITCHIP>) {
    chomp($_);
    my $hostname = $_;
    my $tl     = 0;
    my $t      = Net::SSH2->new(
        #Host => $hostname,
        #Prompt =>
            #'/(?m:^(?:[\w.\/]+\:)?[\w.-]+\s?(?:\(config[^\)]*\))?\s?[\$#>]\s?(?:\(enable\))?\s*$)/',
        #debug=>0
        #Timeout => 30,
        #Errmode => 'return'
        '$hostname', timeout => 30
    ) or $tl = 1;

    my @output = ();

    if ( $tl != 1 ) {
        print "$hostname SSH success\n"; # for printing it in screen
        print OUTPUTS "$date $hostname SSH success\n"; # it will print it in the log_Success.txt
    }
    else {
        my $sshstat = "SSH failed";
        print "$hostname $sshstat\n"; # for printing it in screen
        print OUTPUTF "$date $hostname $sshstat\n"; # it will print it in the log_Fail.txt
    }

    $count++;
}
close(SWITCHIP);
close(OUTPUTS);
close(OUTPUTF);
```

I get an odd error - odd number of elements in hash assigment:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Net/SSH2.pm
1.1.1.1 SSH success
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Net/SSH2.pm
2.2.2.2 SSH success
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Net/SSH2.pm
3.3.3.3 SSH success
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module's [constructor (`new`) expects a `%hash`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.66/lib/Net/SSH2.pm#new_%28_%options_%29). This means that you must supply a list with even number of elements, or a hash variable, so that `new` can build the hash it needs with them. When an odd number of elements is assigned to a hash a warning (that you get) is printed.

The supplied list are the option-value pairs, for convenience written as `option => value, ...`  (even though `option, value ...` would work, too).

The  documented options are: `timeout`, `trace`, `debug`, `compress`, and `sigpipe`.  Thus you cannot supply the hostname when you build the object.

This is done with `connect`

```
my $t = Net::SSH2->new( timeout => 30 ) or $tl = 1;

$t->connect( $hostname ) or $t->die_with_error;
```

See the docs for other options that `connect` supports.

Comment: Its show "Unable to exchange encryption keys (-9 LIBSSH2_ERROR_TIMEOUT) at ./sshrespond.pl line..."

Comment: @DannyLuk You may need to import some constants (`use Net::SSH2 qw(...)`)? See [CONSTANTS](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.66/lib/Net/SSH2.pm#CONSTANTS).  Another thing, judged by the error -- try omitting the timeout option, to see whether it works then.  Also note that under [timeout](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.66/lib/Net/SSH2.pm#timeout) (used as a method)  it says that "_libssh2 1.2.9 or later_" is required

Comment: @DannyLuk At any rate, now you are past the problem of running -- now you can debug the actual access. Note that you may not see this error without `or $t->die_with_error`

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore the commented-out lines, your call to the Net::SSH2 constructor boils down to this:

```
my $t = Net::SSH2->new(
    '$hostname', timeout => 30
) or $tl = 1;
```

That's a list of three arguments (`'$hostname'`, `'timeout'` and `30`), which is an "odd number of elements".

Perhaps you meant:

```
my $t = Net::SSH2->new(
    Host    => $hostname,
    Timeout => 30,
) or $tl = 1;
```

Note also that variable substitution only happens in double-quoted strings.  In a single-quoted string, the `$` character is just a `$`.  So `'$hostname'` seems likely to be an error.

Comment: Thanks, but why all device results are ssh success with invalid IPs. 
1.1.1.1 SSH success
2.2.2.2 SSH success
3.3.3.3 SSH success

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you didn't name all your parameters in the Net::SSH2 constructor. Perl isn't like some other languages where optional arguments can be passed by name. When you call a function like that constructor, your arguments are being interpreted as a hash, so all keys and values must be specified as pairs.

According to the [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH2-0.66/lib/Net/SSH2.pm#new_(_%options_)), it doesn't look like you can set the hostname in the constructor. If you could, the syntax would be `new(hostname => $hostname, timeout => 30);`. Since you can't, call the constructor with just the timeout arguments, then set the hostname afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but why all device results are ssh success with invalid IPs? 1.1.1.1 SSH success 2.2.2.2 SSH success 3.3.3.3 SSH success

Comment: @DannyLuk Because the poor program is confused! The "uneven hash arguments" message is a warning--it's not terminating the program. So the library logic is continuing to run with the wrong data. And I'll remind you that single-quoted variables aren't interpolated, so you passed in a literal string "dollar-sign hostname" instead of the host. Usually after the first error, it doesn't make sense to try to understand what the confused program does.